# python dataframe matching with list items

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Have a dataframe  `df` containing `column (A)` as below 
 `A`

```
["User mapping missing constantly for random users on product PLA-ZA. Hi , Generally, these results look encouraging. Here's what I see at the moment:- On Sept 12, when you ran this script, exactly the same users were shown as not "in sync" as we see in the most recent output."

"History ------------ *** Audit: MLACAMBR 01/10/2018 18:40:05 GMT ",

 "1. find the process ids by doing ps -efl | grep BEMS74397" , 

"kill each of these processes, as follows (for example, if the process ID is 555555):", 

"Troubleshoots from the KMCas well as from the sensor where the connections occurred"]
```

and a Python list **matches**

```
["PLA-ZA","BEMS","MLACAMBR","KMC","OWL",,,,]
```

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Krd.png) 
need a new `column B` to be added which matches strings from list

new Dataframe with matched keyword added as new column

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0KUy.png)

```
matches= "|".join(f"\\b{i}\\b" for i in matches)
df["B"] = df['text'].str.findall(matches,re.IGNORECASE).str.join("|")
df["B"]
```

Comment: What is the problem? @Gangadhar

Comment: Note that `\b` word boundaries won't work well with your data as the terms themselves contain non-word chars like `-`.

Comment: I get below error : bad character range T-P –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

Contents of df before matching: (shows input df)

```
print(df)
```

```
                                             ColumnA
0  User mapping missing constantly for random use...        
1  History ------------ *** Audit: MLACAMBR 01/10...        
2  1. find the process ids by doing ps -efl | gre...        
3  kill each of these processes, as follows (for ...        
4  Troubleshoots from the KMCas well as from the ...
```

**The code:**

```
df['ColumnB'] = ''
matches = ["PLA-ZA","BEMS","MLACAMBR","KMC","OWL"]

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    current_string = row['ColumnA']

    #This block of code extracts all matches that are present in ColumnA of every row in df
    tmpmatch = []
    for x in matches:
        if x in current_string and x not in tmpmatch:
            tmpmatch.append(x)
        tmp_matched_str = ','.join(tmpmatch)
    #Append  the matched string from matches into ColumnB of df
    df.loc[index,'ColumnB'] = tmp_matched_str
```

### Output:

```
print(df)
```

```
                                             ColumnA   ColumnB
0  User mapping missing constantly for random use...    PLA-ZA
1  History ------------ *** Audit: MLACAMBR 01/10...  MLACAMBR
2  1. find the process ids by doing ps -efl | gre...      BEMS
3  kill each of these processes, as follows (for ...          
4  Troubleshoots from the KMCas well as from the ...       KMC
```

which is the expected output!

Comment: if x in current_string and x not in tmpmatch:

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: @GangadharDixit - Can you show me how does your "matches" list look like by doing "type(matches)"

Comment: type(matches)
Out[88]: list

Comment: items in list look like 'OPNSTK',
 ' PLA-ZA',
 'MLACAMBR',
  'OPTO',
 'KMC',
 'ABC',
 'OTHER' is single quote causing any trouble ?

Comment: @GangadharDixit - This code works pretty well for me. Can you update the question and post the code that you have tried by showing the input df and list as well. I just want to see your version of the code that is causing the error so that I can debug.